# static files are not loading for ejs (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, static, ejs

my static files are not loading for ejs. I get following error. I have tried in several ways to get loaded the statics but still I'm getting following errors

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

info-order:63 GET http://localhost:8080/js/order.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

info-order:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

my config file has following code..

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

/*config view engine*/

let configViewEngine = (app) => {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "./src/public")));

  app.set("viewEngine", "ejs");
  app.set("views", "./src/views");
};
module.exports = configViewEngine;
```

And I have link the stylesheet as follow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

my script tag on ejs as foillow..

```
<script src="/js/order.js"></script>
```

Comment: why "./src/public"? can you share the file structure?

Comment: src has views, config, public, routes folders. and server.js file is in main folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/public')));
```

Comment: I tried. but not working.